# Activity not showing correctly in ICS

Tags: android, android-activity, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

[image: Activity doesn't show up]

I have an app that runs fine on my Galaxy S2 and many other phones. However a costumer reported that it doesn't run on his Galaxy Nexus running ICS. The image shows how the app looks like when he runs it on his phone.
Is this is known compatibility issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this related to the OS he use. 
I don't know exactly but I saw some error like this while tetsing the Beta veriosn of ICS.

try to get more details about this version if its a beta version you can do nothing for it !.

Comment: The customer ended up reinstalling his ROM and the problem went away. So, in a way, you were right. Thank you!